# How to select different properties based on variable input in Mulesoft?

Tags: properties, mule, properties-file, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am trying to load a list of property config based on the variable that have passed. Below are an example that I am trying to do it:

let say I have the following on my .properties file

`abc=['Jojo12','Koko34','Gigi56']
 abc2=['Kiki44','Lala11','Hoho32']`

If my variable is `Jojo12` then it will load the following properties *(Should I store this on the same properties file?)*

abc.application.tgh.connection.AgentId= 89
abc.application.tgh.connection.AgentPassword=1************

else if my variable is `Kiki44` then it will load the following properties *(Should I store this on the same properties file?)*

abc2.application.tgh.connection.AgentId= 77
abc2.application.tgh.connection.AgentPassword=2************

How can I achieve the desired result?

Thanks

Comment: how are you "passing in" your variable input? Is it a query param from an http request? Is it on restart of the mule runtime? Deployment of an application?

Comment: Hi @utechtzs it is a payload from an http request

Comment: @JasonLee Can you please share the exact payload as well which http request is sending to you ? It seems like you are using variable name instead of value ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen, hi there for example my request payload is

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<FoodCode_Request>
  <FoodProducts FoodCode=”Jojo12”/> 
</FoodCode_Request > 

Then, I will store the FoodCode = "Jojo12" into a variable for verification of which property config to use. 

My question is I am not sure what is the easiest way to verify it based on the FoodCode, for eg if the value of my variable is "Jojo12" then it will load abc.application.tgh.connection.AgentId= 89 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, it is cumbersome using properties. you will need to iterate each group and see if that user is in there one by one until you have a match.

But you can accomplish the second part using Mule 4 easily:

For property:

```
abc.application.tgh.connection.AgentId= 89
```

Get property:

```
<set-variable variableName="lookupid" value="abc"  />
<logger level="ERROR" message="#[p(vars.lookupid ++ '.application.tgh.connection.AgentId')]" />
```

Comment: Hi @Ryan Carter, Thanks for your response. For the first part, do you know how can i do it without using properties since you mentioned that it is not tat efficient. 

As for second part, as I am running on Mule 3, I think the sample code you provided can be run in my environment right?

Comment: I cant seems to be able to put this code #[p(vars.lookupid ++ '.application.tgh.connection.AgentId')] into element properties field (eg http request or web service consumer) to work. Do you know how should i write? The normal way to reference from properties file is ${application.tgh.connection.AgentId} but now with the addition of variables I am not exactly sure how to write it

Comment: Are you using mule 3 or mule 4?

Comment: I am using mule 3